# unique validation is not working in Update case in YII?

Tags: php, validation, yii, modal-dialog, unique

I have applied unique validation for Employee Code. it is working fine for **Add Emp** case. But i am not getting why it is not working in case of Update, here is the code i have used for this:

My rule method is :

```
public function rules()
{

    return array(
        array('is_active', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('first_name, last_name, employee_code, username, password, role,joining_date,', 'required','on'=>array('create','update')),   

        array('employee_code', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),

        array('employee_code', 'unique','on'=>array('create','update')),
        array('employee_code', 'length', 'min' => 4, 'max'=>4, 'message'=>Yii::t("translation", "{attribute} is too short.")),
        array('username','email'),      
        array('username','valid_username','on'=>array('create')),
        array('username', 'required','on'=>array('forgotPassword')),

        array('currentPassword, newPassword, newPasswordRepeat', 'required','on'=>array('change')),
        array('newPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'newPasswordRepeat','on'=>array('change'),'message'=>'New and Confirm Password do not match.'),
        array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(),'on'=>array('forgotPassword')),
        array('joining_date', 'safe'),
        array('years', 'safe'),
        array('user_id, first_name, last_name, employee_code, username, password, role, joining_date, pending_regular_leave, pending_medical_leave, allocated_regular_leave, allocated_medical_leave, is_active', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
```

Please can someone identify where i am wrong. Please help me.

Comment: [Default scenario names](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/#hh2) are `insert`, `update`, `search`, there is no `create` scenario. Well, unless you specify it manually.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work for update, what do you mean? Is it not validating? Are you getting errors? Can you show your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that the value of field "employee code" **puts in form field** and you are trying to save it. And it is not unique, and it is not save.

Anyway, you can:

```
$employee->validate(array('/* Here is list of attributes, except employee code */'));
```

or:

```
$employee->save(array('/* Here is list of attributes, except employee code */'));
```

in **update action**.

You can also delete scenario in validation rule:

```
array('employee_code', 'unique','on'=>array('insert');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you update record it already exists in the database and the value you are going to validate already exists too. This is why when you do update you should exclude the record you are going to update from the check. Else the check will fail with the message like this

> Employee Code "some value" has already been taken.

For example (new rule with criteria)

```
array(
    'employee_code',
    'unique',
    'criteria' => array(
        'condition' => 'user_id != :id',
        'params' => array(':id' => $this->user_id),
    ),
    'on' => array('create', 'update'),
),
```

I assume that `user_id` is the primary key.

Formally you might want to have different scenarios for `update` and `create` because you do not need any additional checks for the `create` scenario. Single scenario works as well but you might want to do something like this

```
array(
    'employee_code',
    'unique',
    'on' => array('create'),
),
array(
    'employee_code',
    'unique',
    'criteria' => array(
        'condition' => 'user_id != :id',
        'params' => array(':id' => $this->user_id),
    ),
    'on' => array('update'),
),
```

P.S. As mentioned in one of the comments you might want to use `insert` instead of `create` because by default the scenario for newly created model is `insert`. This is more commonly used name.